# Displaying reverse numbers array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to write a program that accepts 10 numbers (ints) from the keyboard. Each number is to be stored in a different element of an array. 
Then my program must then display the contents of the array in reverse order.

```
int [] array = new int [10];
    for(int i = array.length -  1;i >= 0; i--)
    {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number " + (i+1)));
        array[i] = number;

            }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, array[i]);


}
```

I tried to put the JOPtionPane.showMessageDialog outside of the loop but then the program can't find the integer "i". I don't know what to do here :/ Please help :P

Comment: You need two for loops. The first iterates from 0 to 9 and asks for the number and puts it in the array. The second iterates from 9 to 0 and prints the numbers in the array.

Comment: Okay, then you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter your data first, then display it thereafter in the order you desire...

```
int [] array = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number " + (i + 1)));
    array[i] = number;
}

for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, array[i]);
}
```

I'd also be tempted to simply construct a StringBuilder for your final results and then just show the message dialog once only, rather than for every element of the array, but that's up to yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

`i` belongs to the loop scope, that's why you can't use it outside of the loop.

To print the reversed array use another loop

```
// insert the data to the array
int [] array = new int [10];
for(int i = array.length -  1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number " + (i+1)));
    array[i] = number;
}

// print the array
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this,
I have another question, I input numbers 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 (which is 9th number) and then it transfers me to another loop where I get output of 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Why does it cut 1 number? You have any idea?

Comment: @PatrykMichta I'm not sure, I ran it in my computer and it was fine.

Comment: I got it, it was my bad. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've declared in in for loop, so it has loop scope. Declare it before loop to reuse it after loop finishes

```
int i;
for(i = array.length -  1;i >= 0; i--)
```

After that, you can make another loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

to print it in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have another question, I input numbers 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 (which is 9th number) and then it transfers me to another loop where I get output of 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Why does it cut 1 number? You have any idea?

Comment: Oh, that's because second for prints whole table (which size was 10, so it print from index 0 to index 10) but you only have filled from index 9 to index 1, so the unfilled fields in array was 0 (initialization value)

Answer (score 0):

You need two for loops. The first iterates from 0 to 9 and asks for the number and puts it in the array. The second iterates from 9 to 0 and prints the numbers in the array